# display:none works in CSS but not in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a page where a div takes a while to load in.

The simple code in CSS stops it from ever loading:

```
.object-container{
    display:none;
}
```

However, I do need it to display by default, and to only NOT display based on a condition.

So I have:

```
if (x == 1)
{
     alert('here!');
     //$('.object-container').css("display", "none !important");
     $('.object-container').attr('style','display: none !important');
}
```

...and the alert pops up, but every time the DIV displays anyway after the page loads for a while. What might be happening?

Comment: The correct way to do it is `$(".object-container").css("display", "none")`. Other code may be affecting the element; you should be able to inspect the DOM and see how the style rules are being interpreted.

Comment: Same can be achieved by  `$(".object-container").hide()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('.object-container').attr('style','display: none !important');` will overwrite all the inline-styles applied on that particular element.

This may be causing the issue for you. You should change the `display` property alone by

`$('.object-container').hide()`

or

`$('.object-container').css('display','none')`